# $GLOBALS array for WordPress

Tags: core

Is there a file where WordPress defines `$GLOBALS`?

I'm just curious as to what WordPress uses it for and for what purpose.

That's all!

Comment: Was curious too and found the handbook. Is this an comprehensive list of $GLOBALS? https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/global-variables/

Comment: @OliviaChen That's where I ended up first, but it seems to be missing crucial global variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if all of these are WordPress globals, but I did a quick grep type search of the WordPress files and tried to extract all the globals I could..

This is the list I compiled. It may not be perfect, but should *hopefully* represent a lot of the `$GLOBALS` keys that WordPress uses It won't account for globalised variables that aren't explicitly defined as `$GLOBAL`, but still have global scope.

```
$GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop']
$GLOBALS['_wp_sidebars_widgets']
$GLOBALS['blog_id']
$GLOBALS['body_id']
$GLOBALS['comment']
$GLOBALS['comment_depth']
$GLOBALS['content_width']
$GLOBALS['current_site']
$GLOBALS['current_user']
$GLOBALS['custom_background']
$GLOBALS['custom_image_header']
$GLOBALS['debug_bar']
$GLOBALS['editor_styles']
$GLOBALS['is_winIE']
$GLOBALS['link']
$GLOBALS['login_grace_period']
$GLOBALS['month']
$GLOBALS['month_abbrev']
$GLOBALS['more']
$GLOBALS['post']
$GLOBALS['post_type']
$GLOBALS['posts']
$GLOBALS['query_string']
$GLOBALS['request']
$GLOBALS['single']
$GLOBALS['submenu']
$GLOBALS['tab']
$GLOBALS['type']
$GLOBALS['weekday']
$GLOBALS['weekday_abbrev']
$GLOBALS['weekday_initial']
$GLOBALS['wp_admin_bar']
$GLOBALS['wp_filter']
$GLOBALS['wp_object_cache']
$GLOBALS['wp_post_types']
$GLOBALS['wp_query']
$GLOBALS['wp_styles']
$GLOBALS['wp_taxonomies']
$GLOBALS['wp_the_query']
$GLOBALS['wp_version']
```

If you wanted to get a better idea of everything inside the global array you could run something like the following to get a print out, because the above approach was obviously flawed since globals are defined in more than one way.

```
add_action( 'shutdown', 'print_them_globals' );

function print_them_globals() {

    ksort( $GLOBALS );
    echo '<ol>';
    echo '<li>'. implode( '</li><li>', array_keys( $GLOBALS ) ) . '</li>';
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

That should give you a more comprehensive list of variables in the global scope.

Hope that's helpful. :)

Comment: ++++++ wp_filesystem, wp_rewrite, wp_registered_widgets, wp_registered_sidebars, wpdb, current_screen, pagenow, is_IE, is_gecko, is_opera, is_iphone etc..., authordata, wp_roles, wp_scripts, _wp_using_ext_object_cache.. There are probably hundreds out there. Code is Poetry :)

Comment: Well sure, there are plenty more than end up in the global scope, but they aren't defined in the same way, so impossible to factor into my regex pattern.

Comment: Added a function to my answer that will give a more comprehensive list of globals... :)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no.

Globals definitions are scattered throught the codebase.

There's no documentation for most of them, either.

Comment: I think it should also be noted that if you declare ANY variable in the global scope it is automatically added to the $GLOBALS array without ever typing `$GLOBALS[`, so a grep search wouldn't possibly return every global variable in WordPress.

Comment: @steven_desu: I think you meant to post that to t31os' answer.

Comment: It wasn't grep, technically speaking it was a regex pattern match across all files in the WordPress installation directory using Notepad++, my search went along the lines `$GLOBALS([^, ]+)([, ]+)` ... which gave me a bundle of results, which i then copy and pasted, and stripped away all the irrelevant data.

Answer (score 3):

`$GLOBALS` is an associative array containing references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope. This is a PHP language tool.

Global variables can be defined simply by creating a new item in the `$GLOBALS` array like this:

```
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'foo content';
```

WordPress Globals are used to share data across files. They are not defined in any specific place but you can find some of the most important ones here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

PHP makes it even easier to use `$GLOBALS` by allowing you to access the items by simply declaring it using the `global` keyword.

```
global $foo;
$foo = 'foo new content';
```

is the same as:

```
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'foo new content';
```

Please note, if you didn't define `$foo` as global, it will not be linked to the global variable scope.

Some further reading on this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print out all the `$GLOBALS` and get an error 'allowed memory exceeded' or something like that, than put this code inside functions.php:

```
if(!function_exists("print_all_globals")){
    function print_all_globals() {
       $test = array_keys($GLOBALS);
       echo "<pre style='background:blue;color:white;'>";
       print_r($test);
       echo "</pre>";
       exit;
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','print_all_globals');
}
```