# Contact Form 7 filter similar to preprocess_comment

Tags: filters, plugin-contact-form-7

Does the Contact Form 7 plugin have a filter similar to WordPress's [preprocess_comment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment)?

I'll be using this filter to check the body of the message for certain words and call [wp_die()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) to display a message and prevent further processing of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **wpcf7_before_send_mail** is what you're looking for.

You can find some examples of it in action in [this unofficial documentation](http://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/) and in [this support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-insert-contact-name-and-email-in-database-after-successful-submission) where the plugin developer gives some guidance on using it..

Comment: Thanks Jay that was exactly what I was looking for. One more problem, I'd like to check if this hook exists before `add_action()` I though of using `has_action()` to do it. But I find that even if the plugin isn't installed `add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','my_func')` doesn't show any error or warning. Is it OK if I leave to this way ro should I check for a hook's existence before using `add_action()`

Comment: This other question has a nice answer for that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72652/check-if-action-hook-exists-before-adding-actions-to-it -- in short, check if the plugin is active rather than if the hook is available.